# Overloading a function for a generic type vs for a given type and its children

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, type-traits

I am trying to write a pair of overloaded functions, one that must be called for a pointer to a type that is not a B or a child of B, and the second must be called for pointers to B and children of B. At first I tried to use specialization of the template for B, but this doesn't work for derived classes of B. So I looked up SFINAE and `enable_if` etc but couldn't get it to work.

The signature of the generic function is

(1) `template<typename T> int f(T *t)`

For the other I tried to use `enable_if` and `is_base_of` like so:

(2) `template<typename T> int f(typename enable_if<is_base_of<B, T>::value, T>::type *t)`

but always (1) gets called. I tried to replace (1) by the negation of (2):

(1b) `template<typename T> int f(typename enable_if<!is_base_of<B, T>::value, T>::type *t)`

and now I get errors for all Ts whether or not they are (children of) B.

What am I doing wrong? What is the solution?

Test code is as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B {};
class D : public B {};
class C {};

// (1)
/* template<typename T>
int f(T *t)
{ cout << "T\n"; } */

// (1b)
template<typename T>
int f(typename enable_if<!is_base_of<B, T>::value, T>::type *t)
{ cout << "T\n"; }

// (2)
template<typename T>
int f(typename enable_if<is_base_of<B, T>::value, T>::type *t)
{ cout << "B\n"; }

int main()
{
  B b;
  D d;
  C c;
  f(&b);    // Want B; get T with (1), dont compile with (1b)
  f(&d);    // Want B; get T with (1), dont compile with (1b)
  f(&c);    // Want T; get T with (1), dont compile with (1b)
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `is_base_of<B, T>::value, T>::type` won't magically deduce `T` and use it as `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple workaround is to pass the pointer again as a second function argument that is used to discriminate between the two versions

```
template<typename T>
void fImpl(T* t, const void*) { 
   std::cout << "general";
}

template<typename T>
void fImpl(T *b, const B*) {
   std::cout << "specific";
}

template<typename T>
void f(T *t) { 
   fImpl(t, t);
}
```

Comment: Nice.  This might be best for the OP since they actually do not have C++11

Comment: Genius! Works perfectly for me.

Comment: You can even simplify it and rely on both `static_cast` and overloading at the same time here (see [this](https://godbolt.org/g/7A0Rlo) as an example).

Answer (score 4):

Moving the SFINAE into the template parameters we can use

```
// if not B or a descendant
template<typename T, typename enable_if<!is_base_of<B, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void f(T *t)
{ cout << "T\n"; }

// only if B or a descendant
template<typename T, typename enable_if<is_base_of<B, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void f(T *t)
{ cout << "B\n"; }
```

And then running it against

```
int main()
{
  B b;
  D d;
  C c;
  f(&b);    // Want B; get T with (1), dont compile with (1b)
  f(&d);    // Want B; get T with (1), dont compile with (1b)
  f(&c);    // Want T; get T with (1), dont compile with (1b)
  return 0;
}
```

We get

```
B
B
T
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f346758cece3b14)</kbd>

I also made the functions void functions since you did not have any return statements.

Comment: Thanks, that works! However is there a way to get it to work without default template arguments? My solution needs to also work on pre-c++11 where I'm using variants of `is_base_of` and `enable_if` but now it barfs on the default template argument.

Comment: @chengiz I'm not sure.  When I use SFINAE this is how I am most comfortable with it.  I am still learning it.

Answer (score 3):

`typename enable_if<!is_base_of<B, T>::value, T>::type` is non deducible, so you have to call explicitly:

```
f<B>(&b);    // Want B;
f<D>(&d);    // Want B;
f<C>(&c);    // Want T;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cde2503c4dde9a5)

To be deducible, you may use SFINAE with one of the classical way: return type

```
// (1b)
template<typename T>
enable_if_t<!is_base_of<B, T>::value>
f(T* t)
{ cout << "T\n"; }

// (2)
template<typename T>
enable_if_t<is_base_of<B, T>::value>
f(T* t)
{ cout << "B\n"; }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9544095cddedf2a)

or as template parameter:

```
// (1b)
template<typename T, enable_if_t<!is_base_of<B, T>::value>* = nullptr>
void f(T* t)
{ cout << "T\n"; }

// (2)
template<typename T, enable_if_t<is_base_of<B, T>::value>* = nullptr>
void f(T* t)
{ cout << "B\n"; }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f42a99c03800e7f1)